# How can I give serial number for the each slave in Jmeter distributed testing?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, distributed-testing

I want to run jmeter distributed setup, but for some reason I need to Identify each slave with serial number, how can I give the serial number to all slaves like one slave has serial number 1, another is 2 and so on.

Is there any function in jmeter? giving in user input file is not the feasible solution for my setup. Think that only I have access to the master system.

Answer (score 1):

When you start those slaves you have to pass the variable with -J argument like that:

```
    for slave in slaves:           
        serial_index += 1
        run_jmeter_server_cmd = 'nohup java -jar "/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname={0}" -Dserver_port={1} -Jserial_index={3} > /dev/null 2>&1 '.format(hostname, port, serial_index)
```

And serial_index must be in User Defined Variables in test plan:
serial_index: ${__P(serial_index)}
Windows batch:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do (
   echo %x
   jmeter -n -t C:\User\Scriptname.jmx -Jusers=0 -Jserial_number=%x
)
```

Linux bash:

```
for i in {1..5}
    cd $JMETER_DIR/bin/
    DIRNAME=`dirname $0`   
    nohup java $JVM_ARGS -jar "$JMETER_DIR/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$host" -Dserver_port=\$port -s -Jpoll=\$i > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done;
```

Comment: Can you put the same above code in the form of                             
          jmeter -n -t C:\User\Scriptname.jmx    -Jusers=0   format so that I can understand better

Comment: The same like you send Users. Or i did not get the question correctly

Comment: sending users is same for all slaves but I need to send differet number for different slaves, such as 1 for first 2 for second 3 for third so on

Answer (score 0):

If you have access only to the master system you will not be able to "set" anything, you can only use [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) and/or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions in order to distinguish where your Test Plan is running and use these functions i.e. in [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) i.e. to run different branches of the Test Plan on different slaves or identify which slave produced this or that result.

Comment: Then is there no ways to find it out?